# Yesod: querying `persist` database with a custom primary key

Tags: haskell, yesod, persist

Supposing that I have a SQL table with `persist`, and that I have a custom `Text` as primary key instead of the auto-incrementing `Int64` key.

For example, my database definition is thus:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
TorrentD
    infoHash Text
    ipAddr [Text]
    Primary infoHash
    deriving Show
|]
```

**Supposing that I then have a plain `Text` value, what is the idiomatic way to query the database for a row with a primary key matching my `Text` value?**

`runDB $ get $ toSqlKey ("test" :: Text)` doesn't work as `toSqlKey` doesn't support custom primary keys and thus expects expects an `Int64`.

Creating the key manually and running `runDB $ get $ Key $ PersistText ("test" :: Text)` doesn't work as it is giving me an error about `Key` not being in scope (although I do have [`Database.Persist.Class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.6/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:Key) in my imports).

Comment: I don't think the above schema in persistent makes your primary key as Text. The line `Primary infoHash` just adds uniqueness constraint to your schema. Your primary key is still `Int64`. You can inspect the db to verify it.

Comment: The schema is `CREATE TABLE "torrent_d"("info_hash" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"ip_addr" VARCHAR NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("info_hash"))`.

The mechanism for creating a custom primary key is [documented here](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#primary-and-foreign-keys).

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I've found (the?) (an?) answer. It's not very pretty, but:

```
get (TorrentDKey {unTorrentDKey = torrentPInfoHash torrent})
```

works.

The `unTorrentDKey` is something generated inside the template haskell.

It looks like i'll have to pepper

```
let primaryKey = TorrentDKey {unTorrentDKey = torrentPInfoHash torrent}
```

around in my code.

Comment: Yeah, this is a proper way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I didn't look at the generated THaskell but a bit surprising it isn't just `TorrentDId`.  You can avoid having to use the field name and can just use the constructor like this: `TorrentDKey $ torrentPInfoHash torrent`